# sql query for count the number which have same value

Tags: laravel

i have patients visit table, so i have to know how much the particular patient had visited hospital. i had used below query:

(select count(id) from visit where  cid = cid) as vno.

so, i want to count the all same cid value. and display in 'vno' column . and one patient had only one cid. so if that particular patient had visit again and again. i need to know that how many time that particular patient had visited

and below i have image of visit page

[image]

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

**I think its work**

```
 $noOfVisit = DB::table('visit')->whereCid($cid)->count();
 dd($noOfVisit);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `hasMany` relationship for `Patient` model?

```
public function visits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Visit::class, 'cid', 'cid');
}
```

Then in your view

```
{{ $patient->visits->count() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $unique_visitors = Visit::pluck('cid')->unique()->toArray();
        $visitor_count = [];
        foreach($unique_visitors as $visitor_id)
        {
        $visitor_count[$visitor_id] = count(Visit::where('cid','=',$visitor_id)->get());
        }

// output would be an array with key as cid and value as their visit counts
// Something like this
    Array(
    [1] => 13;
    [2] => 6;
    )
```